# Insert string after find word in vba word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need help, I new in vba word.

I have word document with shapes object.
I success to get a specific shape that I need to edit with this line:

```
Dim c As Range
Set c = ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
```

Now In the range I want to find string and add lines after the specific string.

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi Tal, unfortunately that's not how it works. You need to give it a go yourself. If you have a go at it and still can't do it then you just need to update your question to show us what you've tried and we'll be more than happy to help.

Comment: I edit my question. I hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand How to add text to shape, but how i can add text without change the design.
When i used with the code from Darren Bartrup-Cook answer it's change the design of the shape object.

[image: before add text]

[image: after add text]

Thanks,
Tal

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so `c` holds a reference to your shape.
You can get at the text in the shape using `c.Text`.

The VBA keyword `Instr` returns the starting position of one string within another.
So, if you have a variable defined as `sTextToFind` holding the value `" DEF "` - note the spaces on either side so it finds a whole word, and another `lPos` to hold the numeric location of that string.

`lPos = InStr(c, sTextToFind)` will return where your text to find starts in your string.

You can then insert your new text into your existing text using `LEFT` and `MID` to split the existing text apart:
`c.Text = Left(c, lPos + Len(sTextToFind) - 1) & "my new text " & Mid(c, lPos + Len(sTextToFind))`

So your updated code:

```
'Shape(1) holds "ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO"
Sub Test()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim lPos As Long
    Dim sTextToFind As String

    sTextToFind = " DEF "

    Set c = ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange
    lPos = InStr(c, sTextToFind) 'Returns position 4 (the space between C & D).

    'Returns "ABC DEF my new text GHI JKL MNO"
    c.Text = Left(c, lPos + Len(sTextToFind) - 1) & "my new text " & Mid(c, lPos + Len(sTextToFind))

End Sub
```